# checking values on (click) button or at <ion-input>

Tags: ionic-framework

Good evening,

```
***<ion-item>
   <on-input     type="integer" placeholder="integer value"  clearInput="true" [(ngModel)]="myinput"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
      <button ion-button  (click) ="addmesurement()" color="light">***
```

I just need to make sur that **myinput** is not null before calling  the function addmesurement. is there any contole i can add in `<ion-put>` like "Not null" for example.
i found some suggestions for some problems like mine but the solutions are a litte bit old and complicated. does ionic3/4 provide any solution easy to implement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be far better to make that check down in the function addmesurement or make a new function in the ts file:

```
addmesurementWithCheck() {
    if (!this.myinput) return; 
    this.addmesurement();
}
```

and then call this function from your button in the html-file